# Does "there's more to come" require a past tense after it?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, verbs, past-tense

I wrote the following phrase:

> There's more to come once this pull request get merged

(a [*pull request*](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) is something that can be *merged*)

I saw on various places people using *There's more to come once `+ subject + past tense`*.

Is using present tense here correct or should I say *There's more to come once this pull request got merged*?

Comment: 3rd person singular present tense (*gets*) is correct there.  I'd like to see some examples of other people using past tense for that construction; my guess is that either they are incorrect or you are misinterpreting the construction.

Comment: The short answer is "There was more to come once this p-r got merged," and "There is more to come once this p-r gets merged." Both are euphonious in Br E. Once I've got my head round the unconventional (is to come)  futures, the impersonals (there is/was), and the crypto-passives (get) I'll hope to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hellion's comment above is the right answer:

> There's more to come once this pull request *gets* merged.

You are correct to use present tense here, although we use *gets* instead of *get*. This is because *gets* is in an independent clause: "this pull request gets merged," which looks a bit weird on its own but is nevertheless a complete thought. The subject here is *pull request*, so the verb should be in singular 3rd person (it).

Now, I've been struggling to explain why it should be in the present tense. In English, almost any sentence set in the present or future with a clause that starts with *once [something happens]* uses the present tense for the thing happening. e.g.

> Once we go to the beach, we will make a sand castle.
>
> Once I add this detail, the painting is done.

The best explanation I can come up with is this: we're not talking about something happening as an event in itself; we're talking about it as a condition of something else happening. In order for more to come, the pull request has to be merged. i.e.:

> if (pullRequest == merged) {More.come();}

(The metaphor breaks down because the verb in "There is more to come" is *is*, not *come*, but you get the idea.)

Another correct way to phrase this would be to use the present perfect tense, like so:

> There's more to come once this pull request *has been* merged.

And that works for complicated reasons involving relative timing when things happen.